# FAB (Floating Action Button) not showing on Canvas in GX16 u11

Tags: floating-action-button, genexus, genexus-sd

Since I made a Gx16 u7 version update to Gx16 u11, FAB button stop showing in the panel. I use this configuration to show a button over a Canvas Control:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1G9P.png)

Hope you guys can help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing grid type to Flex Grid. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with ww pattern, and you changed the web layout of wwNameTransaction, you should Edit -> Apply Default (Web Layout).